# Windows-style taskbar functionality in OS X?

Tags: switching, windows

Looking for an OS X add-on that will enable Windows-like (one-click) functionality for switching between different windows of a single application.

Example: I have 5 maximized Chrome windows open, and wish to switch to a specific window. My current options are Exposé, the "Window" file menu, and Cmd-`. None of them are ideal because they take more than one click to execute, which is why I miss the taskbar in Windows. (For those of you unfamiliar with the taskbar, it displays a list of all your system-wide open windows similarly to how tabs are displayed in modern browsers.

So basically, I want to see a list of all of my open windows, and be able to toggle between them with a single click.

Comment: What version of OSX are you using? Lion? Snow Leopard?

Comment: Also are you using a Mouse or Trackpad

Answer (score 9):

Could perhaps [HyperDock](http://hyperdock.bahoom.com/) or [DockView](http://kapeli.com/dockview/) meet your needs?

Comment: +1 for HyperDock. If you like HyperDock, you might also like [HyperSwitch](http://bahoom.com/hyperswitch/) from the same developer, especially if you prefer keyboard shortcuts. It's still in beta, but I haven't had any issues so far.

Answer (score 9):

try [uBar](http://brawersoftware.com/products/ubar), which is a Windows-style taskbar for OS X (I am the developer). Just set Window Grouping to Never in the preferences, and it will display each individual window in the bar.

[image: uBar, the taskbar for OS X]

Comment: Icons can not be rearranged making it useless for me. I need to be able to create control and predictability.

Answer (score 3):

My solution to this is to not maximize windows: if I have one large window open in the middle, I'll leave ~50 pixels of open monitor on each side (less on the top) and I'll arrange ancillary windows (chat, terminal, Stickies, etc.) so various edges of them stick out beyond the edge of the big central window. Apps that have larger windows (browsers, email, etc.) that I access less-frequently I'll leave in the middle and click on the Dock icon to bring all of them forward and choose which one to use (usually, there's only one window in this sort of app in my normal usage).

If I have a ton of windows open in a certain app (usually BBEdit or Excel), I'll make sure none of them completely occlude another so I can, at the very least, get to any window in two clicks: one on the Dock icon and the second on an edge of the window I want; in some cases, I'll four-finger-swipe to get Exposé and then click on the document window I want.

Answer (score 3):

Expose is the answer, you just need to configure it properly.

I use a trackpad (on my desktop mac!) and have a four finger swipe to bring up expose. With a mouse you might want to investigate activating expose with a screen corner or keyboard command (eg: left hand on the keyboard, right hand on the mouse).

Properly configured, expose is fast. It also gives you a bigger click target than the task bar.

There is no way to get the exact task bar functionality on OS X, you are going to have to learn a different workflow. But once you learn it, you'll be just as efficient.

Comment: I believe this isn't entirely correct. Hyperdock provides the ability to pick different windows with just one click

Answer (score 2):

Using your Chrome example,

Hold CTRL and click on Chrome icon on the dock, it will bring up a list of Chrome Window that is currently opened.

Comment: This is the same as right-click (if you use right-clicks). The problem is this list is always **alphabetical**, and for windows which change title frequently (for example browser windows with multiple tabs), the order keeps changing. It's hard to tell which was the most recently used window.

Answer (score 2):

After trying MANY dock style products, at the suggestion of someone earlier in this post, I trued [uBar](https://brawersoftware.com/products/ubar). (I am in no way affiliated with uBar, just a new customer).

My particular circumstances require a working dock on multiple screens (I have 4 total, including my laptop screen). The majority of the tool bars out there just remake the Mac Dock, which is ok, but has erratic behavior when you move from one screen to another.

uBar is the first window dock I have found that will put a dock on EVERY screen, which for me is a HUGE win. It will reduce and expand windows with a single click and change from one app to the other easily. This doc essentially mimics a Windows toolbar even down to having a quick launch area on the bottom right with the date and time. (DATE!!!) I have been a flustered Mac user for years because of companies that choose to use Mac over PC for the employees, but have been a Windows users since Windows 3.1 really.

If you are a Windows user crossing to Mac, this will ease your passage.

---- update after about 3 years ----

I tried it, and had to ditch it. The issue is that while using multiple monitors, I have found that the monitors peg the CPU. But sadly so did the UBar. I logged a few tickets and stopped using it after I burnt out a laptop.

My company was kind enough to replace the crispy laptop with a 32 gb version with an i7, which handles the monitors better, as long as I have a cooling pad underneath.

But unfortunately, even with the cooling pad, if I fired up the ubar, the fans would scream non stop and there was no way to cut down the CPU and memory usage.

As a result, I just got used to using the native mac capabilities. Probably the best thing I could do under the circumstances, but still curious if someone would make something better. I am going to look at a few of the new entries associated with this thread soon.

Comment: It works great, too bad titles are not shown, it shows windows from all spaces, as well as does not allow you to reorder icons.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen anything quite what ur looking for, but [Witch](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/witch/id412485838?mt=12) does a good job of rotating through all open windows whether they are minimized or not.

Answer (score 1):

[iTaskbar](http://itaskbar.com) is a product that I'm affiliated with, so be sure to check out other's reviews of it. At the moment it's the only product in this category since creating a taskbar on OS X is not as trivial as on other operating systems. ;)

[image]

We hope it will be helpful to all those people who, just like us, need a taskbar to work efficiently.

Comment: Please have a look at the [FAQ], especially the part about self-promotion.

Comment: Sorry for having violated the rules. It's true that I'm affiliated to the product, I didn't know I had to state it. I just thought the link was exactly the answer to the question of the user. My bad :)

Comment: @krav We have a very nice system where anyone can edit things. I would suggest you put any common information in your [profile](http://apple.stackexchange.com/users/48184/krav) and if you answer some unrelated questions well, you'll get enough reputation here to comment and participate on [meta] where we can help you stay on track with respect to what's marketing and what's considered spam.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your comment. I will edit my profile as you suggest ASAP.

Comment: Saving future me a click: the website has been offline since April 2017

Answer (score 0):

And don't forget that holding down option when clicking between different application windows (or to the Desktop) will hide the app you're clicking out of.  If you're a OOTMOOTK (one on the mouse, one on the keyboard) type user, it makes a world of difference.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a mouse so cannot test using one.

**With a Trackpad**

You can use a gesture to swipe the "Application's Exxposé"

The "Application's Exposé" shows you thumbnails and scaled windows of the current Application.

[image]

Or if you hover over any app in the dock which has open windows (does not have to be the currently active) and use the gesture "Application's Exposé" will show you the windows for that app.

You can then click into one of them or gesture back to your current app.

Setup the gesture in the Trackpad preference pane in System Preferences

[image]

**Using the keyboard**

You can do the same by setting a hot key to replace the gesture part. But it will only show the current apps windows.

This is set under the Application Windows in Mission Control preference pane in System Preferences.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to check out Contexts: https://contexts.co.  It seems to do a better job of finding all the windows than other things I've tried in the past.

Answer (score 0):

#### Try **[Mac Taskbar](https://mac-taskbar.com)** (2023).

[image: Screenshot of Mac Taskbar 2024]

It's **new** and **lightweight**. I am the developer. It is free for now. You will also find the public git repo to report issues. I will fix them quickly.

The main reason I created Mac Taskbar is because uBar really is bloated as this point:

[image: Mac Taskbar vs. uBar comparison]

Many features are still missing,  I will priotize them **according to [user feedback](https://github.com/inndevs/mac-taskbar-public/issues)**.

Main Features:

- Performance Optimized
- Resizing of existing windows
- Multi Monitor support
- Detecting most scenarios when to update GUI
- Low CPU, low memory footprint due to Dual-dispatching algorithm in
  order to max performance
- Auto-Startup

Comment: An actual link and a description what the application does might help to make this look less like spam.

Comment: @nohillside I updated my answer to look more serious.

Comment: long way to go ...

Answer (score 0):

I have been developing a Windows-style taskbar for macOS for quite some time now and it's finally released as a public beta

Check it out: https://lawand.io/taskbar/

Please note, this beta expires on April 1st, 2024. Afterwards, a license is required.

Comment: Thanks for self disclosing your product. Seems like a good option for people looking to get this on today's OS choices.

Comment: @bmike thanks :) and thank you for updating my answer, it's a good thing to make it clear that the app isn't free. it's won't be too expensive, probably the same cost as similar apps

Comment: I’m a big fan of software I pay for with money instead of time or being sold. Best of luck with the launch!