# Multi-column application list on uBar

Tags: applications, dock, macos

Is there any way to configure [uBar](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/32318/ubar) so that the application list spans on several columns (instead of having to scroll as we need to by default)?

One column = need to scroll:

[image]

Several columns = no need to scroll:

[image]

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the maintainer of the software? If so, did they reply? Please [edit] your question and tell us.