# Preventing uBar from opening folders when clicking on a non-leaf element of the start menu

Tags: macos

Is it possible to configure [uBar](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/32318/ubar) so that clicking on a non-leaf element of the start menu does not open the corresponding folder?

E.g. if I click on "Applications" (a non-leaf element), it will open the application folder:

[image]

I've been using a bunch of start menus and it is the first time I see this behavior as the default setting. As a dwell clicking user it's very annoying.

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.