# Dock alternative respecting virtual Desktops

Tags: dock, 3rd-party

I'm searching a replacement for Apple's Dock.

Constraints:

- Should look/work similar to Windows 7's task bar
- No Window groupings
- Don't show windows of other virtual Desktops

  - ↑ This is very important and the reason for opening a new question on this topic.
- paid / free ok

**What I've found**
There are several tools out there. **ubar** is often mentioned. It's actually almost perfect for the job, but it also shows windows of other virtual desktops.

Comment: The dock shows primarily applications, not windows.

Comment: Maybe consider this tool: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/463703/456705

Answer (score 0):

###### [Contexts ($9.99)](https://contexts.co/)

Contexts kind of offers this functionality (You need to adjust the settings though).

However

- It does not replace the dock (does not make it vanish)
- It cannot be place in the bottom center (like the dock)
- I does not provide a "open new window of this app" option, so you will ultimately still need to use the dock for these actions.

Nice-to-haves:

- It offers Application-switching (Alt-Tab) functionality, that respects virtual desktops.